# FontFamily defined in XAML per platform

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms project I would like to define the Form family onect per platform and the use that in the application.

So far I've hardcoded the FontFamily per controltype

```
  <Style x:Key="TahomaBase_Label" TargetType="Label" BaseResourceKey="SubtitleStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma" />
  ...
 </Style>
```

Is it posible to set Fotnfamily globally in my XAML code preferable itn a `OnPlatform` tag?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Define a style in the App.xaml and then reference that style throughout the app. That way you can set the font once in the App.xaml using the OnPlatform tag and never have to worry about OnPlatform in all your other XAML files.

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="PlatformFontSample.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="FontFamilyName" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="MarkerFelt-Thin" Android="OpenSans" WinPhone="Segoe UI" />
            <Style x:Key="FontLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource FontFamilyName}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{DynamicResource FontLabel}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
```

Comment: Thank you that was my first try but I get an error:

An exception of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException' occurred in Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Position 11:8. Type FontFamily not found in xmlns

Comment: My bad; I edited it accordingly. The `x:TypeArguments` property needed to be `x:String` instead of `FontFamily`.

Comment: ok. But then I just get an new error: 

Additional information: Position 8:6. Property Resources is null or is not IEnumerable

I've created a new project and added your code.

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing your `ResourceDictionary` tag. Updated the sample again with a full App.xaml.

Comment: Yes I did.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I found this thread, much cleaner to do it this way!

Comment: Do keep in mind, the OnPlatform code is deprecated on my answer by now.  Check this on how to change it: https://montemagno.com/important-onplatform-changes-xamarin-forms/